# Show that this set is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (or not)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Is the following set a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$:
>
> $$U=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
> x_{1}  \\ 
> x_{2}  
> \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}:ax_{1}+x_{2}=0\right\}, \text{ whereby } a \in \mathbb{R}$$

We need to show $3$ things:

1.) $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$

2.) $U \neq \emptyset$ (empty set)

3.) For $U_{1},U_{2} \in U$ arbitrary and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary  we have that

(i) $U_{1}+U_{2} \in U$

(ii) $\lambda \cdot U_{1} \in U$

1.) is obvious because this is already mentioned in the set.

2.) We have $\begin{pmatrix}
0  \\ 
0  
\end{pmatrix} \in U$, so $a \cdot 0+0=0 \Leftrightarrow 0=0$ so the empty set isn't included in $U$.

3.(i)

Let $U_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}
c_{1}  \\ 
d_{1}  
\end{pmatrix}$ and let $U_{2}= \begin{pmatrix}
c_{2}  \\ 
d_{d}  
\end{pmatrix}$

$\Rightarrow ac_{1}+d_{1}=0$ and $ac_{2}+d_{2}=0$

$U_{1}+U_{2}= \begin{pmatrix}
c_{1}+  c_{2} \\ 
d_{1}+  d_{2}
\end{pmatrix}$ is in $U$?

So we need to show that $a(c_{1}+c_{2})+(d_{1}+d_{2})=0$

We know that $d_{1}=-ac_{1}$ and $d_{2}=-ac_{2}$ so put that into the equation we get: $a(c_{1}+c_{2})+(-ac_{1}-ac_{2})=0 \Leftrightarrow 0=0$

So we are done with 3.(i) and what remains is just 3.(ii) left but how would you do it?

Did I do it correctly till here at all?

Comment: $\phi\neq\emptyset$, phi is not the empty set

Comment: didnt know a way to write empty set in latex so i have taken phi because it looks same :p

Comment: \emptyset :P Easy peasy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U_1 \in U$, then $ac_1+d_1=0,$

Multiply both sides by $\lambda$,

$$\lambda(ac_1+d_1)=\lambda0$$

$$a(\lambda c_1)+\lambda d_1 = 0$$

hence $\lambda U_1 \in U$

Comment: Thank you! Everything else I did is correct?

Comment: yup, seems fine. though presentation wise, i would write $a(c_1+c_2)+(d_1+d_2)=(ac_1+d_1)+(ac_2+d_2)=0$

Comment: extra optional exercise: prove that solution to a homogeneous linear system of $n$ variables forms a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$